# centralized API documentation for microservices

Tags: api, documentation, microservices

My team and I are currently building multiple services in parallel. We have the benefit of building all the services from scratch. I would like the ability to automatically display all API endpoints, from all services, in one page/site.  This would be helpful because (among other things):

1. I don't have to go to multiple documentation sites to see what are the available endpoints in my entire "system".
2. It'll be a good first step to determine if any of the services should be split, combined or simply refactored.

Some of our services are in Django and the [rest-swagger](http://swagger.io/) module is a great help. But I don't see how I can combine rest-swagger documentation from multiple services into a single documentation page/site.

I'm currently looking through [this site](http://microservices.io/index.html) and anything related to the [Netflix experience](http://nginx.com/blog/microservices-at-netflix-architectural-best-practices/) but could not find a solution to my problem. Maybe centralized documentation isn't a big deal with 600+ services at Netflix, but that's hard to believe.

Can anyone suggest a tool or method to have a combined API documentation for all services in a microservice architecture?

My ideal scenario of what happens when a service is changed:

1. I click on the link to see the list of endpoints in my system.
2. A teammate updates a service and also it's documentation.
3. I refresh the page I am currently and I see that change made from step #2.

Comment: HI, have you found a project that can draw out a diagram of your 200+ api services?  Looking exactly for this tool.  We already have API Blueprints per service, need something that can give a top-level view.  THANKS!

Comment: @Cmag I have not found a tool to do this. What I ended up doing was using https://github.com/tripit/slate and a Makefile to combine documentation from the multiple GitHub repositories which housed the microservices code.

Comment: Hey @rexposadas I'd be interested in knowing what you came up with, as I am now writing a post covering this very topic on best practises for microservice documentation after being asked a handful of times at our Technical Writers meetup about the subject.

Comment: @ChrisChinchilla I know this response is very delayed, but what seems to worked for us is to have markdown files serve as documentation in each repository. For us, the code for a single micro-service lives in a repository.

Our documentation is in a single github repo (We use Slate).  We deploy the slate app and the CI/CD process pulls all the markdown files from the other repositories, includes them in the slate project and deploys the new docs.

Comment: @rexposadas No worries, I ended up writing the articles and it follows similar ideas really.

https://blog.codeship.com/documenting-microservices/

Answer (score 1):

With my exp, you have some paths.

1. http://readme.io/
2. Make a wiki with JIRA, Redmine.
3. In Github create a repo for exclusive docs.
4. Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any existing tool rather I'm just putting my thought on where to do it.

From what the OP describe, they are already building a micro services architecture using Netflix stack. There should be a repository to config the name (or URL) for each of the services and the 'config server' or 'service registry' will read from that. To me, that's the perfect place to put the reference to each of the micro-service's documentation under their own entries. This way you get the benefit of maintaining the documentation and code at same place, plus you could potentially also collect run time information like instance/connections count if you hook into the config/registry server.

Answer (score 0):

Being in similar situation I am looking to adopt https://readthedocs.org/ with GIT backed.